# How to get a Matrix exported to Excel just as it is from PowerBI

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I want to be able to export an matrix table in powerBI desktop to this:
[image]

Because right now I need to use "text to columns" before I can work with the data.
[image]

I saw this post from Microsoft, but I don't understand how to activate it.
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-my/blog/export-to-excel-improvements-for-table-and-matrix-visuals-preview/

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Power BI does provide an opportunity to build an Excel Pivot report from data in a matrix visualization once the report is published to the Power BI service. From the service,  select the ellipsis in the upper right corner. Then select Analyze In Excel. An Excel file will be created. Open this Excel file and you will be able to create a pivot from the Power BI dataset.

Comment: But i've not published it in PowerBI Service? I'm using desktop version. But it's maybe the same problem no matter where.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working when I published it to Service.